# How do I fix this error? Cannot read properties of null

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
import axios from "axios";

const BASE_URL = "http://localhost:5000/api/";
const TOKEN =
  JSON.parse(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("persist:root")).User).currentUser
    .accessToken || "";

export const publicRequest = axios.create({
  baseURL: BASE_URL,
});

export const userRequest = axios.create({
  baseURL: BASE_URL,
  header: { token: `Bearer ${TOKEN}` },
});
```

The error:

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'User') Module. C:/Users/hp/Desktop/ecommerce 2/client/src/requestMethods.jsx:4 1 | import axios from "axios"; 2 | 3 | const BASE_URL = "localhost:5000/api"; > 4 | const TOKEN = 5 | JSON.parse(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("persist:root")).User).currentUser 6 | .accessToken || ""; 7 |

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'User')
Module.<anonymous>
C:/Users/hp/Desktop/ecommerce 2/client/src/requestMethods.jsx:4
  1 | import axios from "axios";
  2 | 
  3 | const BASE_URL = "http://localhost:5000/api/";
> 4 | const TOKEN =
  5 |   JSON.parse(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("persist:root")).User).currentUser
  6 |     .accessToken || "";
  7 |

Comment: Please give a [mre] - React and Axios seem to be irrelevant, what matters it's what's in local storage.

Comment: this is null JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("persist:root"))

Comment: There is no react in your code. I'm going to remove that tag.

Comment: Your persistence strategy is...odd, if you have to parse a property of an item you've added to localStorage. Why not store `.User` pre-parsed, instead of parsing it every time?

Answer (score 2):

That error message means you tried to access the `User` property on an object that is `null`.

The localStorage key `persist:root` doesn't seem to contain anything. [localStorage.getItem](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/getItem) can return `null`, so you need to check for this before attempting to access properties on the value it's returned. For example:

```
const persistRoot = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('persist:root'));

if (persistRoot) {
  const accessToken = JSON.parse(persistRoot.User).currentUser.accessToken || '';
}
```

Depending on how your data is structured, you may need additional checks in that chain to make sure values exist. You may find [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) syntax to be useful for this.

Answer (score 2):

Try like this, it should work.

JSON.parse(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("persist:root"))?.user || "{}")?.currentUser?.accessToken

Comment: Could you please format the code properly as code, and perhaps split it into a few lines? It would be great if you could explain what you changed and why! Thanks :)